# CSS Move a heading so it is partially outside the container

Tags: css

you know the default way that a legend is rendered within a fieldset?

I am trying to accomplish the same with an aside. e.g.

```
<aside>
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>content</p>
</aside>
```

What I have right now:

```
aside {
  background-color: #e1d8ee;
  display: block;
  font-style: oblique;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #808080;
  padding: 1em;
}

aside h1, aside h2, aside h3, aside h4, aside h5, aside h6 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #fcc006;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: -12em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #808080;
}
```

No matter what I set the margin-top to, it still stays within the aside - I want it half-inside the aside, half above it, so that h{n} is to aside as legend is to fieldset - where browsers nicely display the legend in the fieldset border.

I just simply do not seem to know enough CSS to make this happen, nor even enough to know the proper search terms to find a solution.

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: What's the relevant html for this snippet?

Comment: The aside will usually be a child of a section or article node, containing information slightly related to but not really related to the section. e.g. if talking about math, it might include a short biographical information about Blaise Pascal. That is what I believe aside is intended for. My use will only have one heading inside it, as the first child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using  "position: relative"  and   positioning the element using "top:"

Example:

```
 aside h1, aside h2, aside h3, aside h4, aside h5, aside h6 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 1em;  
  padding: 0.3em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-color: #808080;
  position: relative;
  top: -1.5em;
  }
```